# Can I use my passport even though it has the wrong place of birth

Tags: usa, passports

I messed up the application, so it was my fault. I was born in another country but I put I was born in my state of residence. Everything else on the passport looks good. Is it possible for me to travel anyway and potentially get it fixed later?

Also I am wondering if it is free to get it corrected. I just got the passport today and checked it.

Comment: Personally, I find quite worrisome the fact that no one in the passport office checked for accuracy the information that you put in your application.

Comment: As per the above, don't you need to show a birth certificate or equivalent to get the passport originally, as per section 1 of [DS-11](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/212239.pdf): `"APPLICANTS BORN OUTSIDE THE UNITED STATES: Submit a previous U.S. passport, Certificate of Naturalization, Certificate of Citizenship, Report of Birth Abroad, or
evidence described below:"`

Answer (score 9):

An incorrect country of birth is a fairly major error on a passport. You should definitely get this error corrected before attempting to use your passport.

To correct a US passport, you would submit [form DS-5504](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/212249.pdf).

> Q. IS THERE A FEE ASSOCIATED WITH THIS FORM?
>   A. There is no fee associated with the use of this form unless expedited service is requested (see below). Your re-issued passport book and/or passport card and any documentary evidence submitted to Passport Services will be returned to you by priority or first class mail, unless overnight delivery is requested.

Comment: Oh sweet it is free. I see the form saying I need new photos but read somewhere else that you don't need new photos if you took them within 90 days (and I just got my passport so I am in this category). Should I ship new photos as well? Thanks for replying!

Comment: Also, do I have to fill out the whole form or just the part I want corrected?

Comment: You have to fill out the entire form.